# How to exclude directory and files from NuGet package built with Octopack via Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, nuget, jenkins-pipeline, nuget-package, octopack

I have a windows service that I need to pack into a nuget package with OctoPack, but I have to exclude a directory called "Config" and a few other config files (these are instance specific and this will be deployed to multiple instances.) However the files are always included no matter what I put in the nuspec file.

Project directory:

```
Config <dir>
Code <dir>
app.config
settings.config
service.csproj
service.nuspec
```

Nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <!-- Required elements-->
        <id>service</id>
        <version>0.0.0</version>
        <description>service for app</description>
        <authors>our team</authors>
    </metadata>
    <!-- Optional 'files' node -->
    <files>
        <file src="**" exclude="Config\" />
        <file src="**" exclude="**\app.config" />
        <file src="**" exclude="**\settings.config" />
    </files>
</package>
```

Jenkins file:

```
bat "dotnet-octo pack --id=service --format=NuPkg --basePath=bin\\x64\\BuildServer --version=0.0.0.${env.BUILD_ID} --overwrite"
```

I'm sure there is an error in my nuspec file or something but I can't find any documentation for my specific case. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried the nuspec with only one of the `<file` lines? Maybe the first is including all files expect the `Config\` directory, but including the `**\app.config` files, and the second is including the `Config\` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was way overthinking this. I just edited the Jenkins file to delete them before packing. Completely forgot that `bat` was an option.

```
bat "del bin\\x64\\BuildServer\\app.config"
bat "del bin\\x64\\BuildServer\\settings.config"
bat "rmdir /s /q bin\\x64\\BuildServer\\Config"
bat "dotnet-octo pack --id=service --format=NuPkg --basePath=bin\\x64\\BuildServer --version=0.0.0.${env.BUILD_ID} --overwrite"
```

However, the correct way to do it via nuspec would have been

```
<files>
    <file src="bin\x64\BuildServer\**\*.*" exclude="bin\x64\BuildServer\app.config;bin\x64\BuildServer\settings.config;bin\x64\BuildServer\Config\*.xml" />
</files>
```

`src` means "include all directories and files in `bin\x64\BuildServer`, where all the dlls and such are after building. And `exclude` means *except* these files. Note *all* paths are relative to where your nuspec file is (this is important!!!).